# Should we expect added elements to the saved entity to be created as well?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I just noticed that when I add a product to my order's list of products (verifying that I indeed have two instead of the original one element there) and save it, the added product doesn't appear in the database. I was expecting it to do be automagically created (since the order itself's being tracked, I imagine that all the elements in its list of products should too).

```
context.Orders.AddOrUpdate(order);
context.SaveChanges();
```

I made a work-around by adding the following loop.

```
context.Orders.AddOrUpdate(order);
foreach (Product product in order.Products)
  context.Products.AddOrUpdate(product);
context.SaveChanges();
```

However, I can't stop feeling that it's hiding the actual issue, rather than resolving it. What can I be missing?

When I load in the orders I made sure in use include the products, of course.

```
using (Context context = new Context())
  Orders = context.Orders
    .Include(order => order.Products)
    ...
    .Where(order => !order.Deleted)
    ...
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Show us the code that does not work!

Comment: @dotctor The code that doesn't work as expected is the first code sample (except I "fix" it by adding the *foreach* loop. If you omit the middle lines, only retaining *AddOrUpdate* and *SaveChanges*, that's the not-working code. Sorry if I was unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`context.Orders.AddOrUpdate(order);` has two completely different effects depending on whether the `Order` is new or existing.

If the `Order` is an existing one (as in your case), the `Order`'s state is set to `Modified` if it has any changes to its *scalar* properties. Changes to its collections or reference properties (if any) are ignored.

This is similar to explicitly setting the `Order`s state to `Modified`, it only affects the `Order`, not its adhering objects.

However, if the `Order` is new, `AddOrUpdate` will change its state to `Added`. This is the same as explicitly setting its state to `Added`. This state change is always recursive (an implementation choice that can be disputed. It may work wonderfully in adding entire object graphs, but it also causes lots of confusion).

So if the `Order` is new, all `Product`s that are *not yet attached to the content* at that point will also be added as new.

That's why your second code sample works for existing `Order`s but may have unexpected results for new ones.

If you swap two lines ...

```
foreach (Product product in order.Products)
  context.Products.AddOrUpdate(product);
context.Orders.AddOrUpdate(order);
context.SaveChanges();
```

... both added and updated `Order`s will be handled correctly, because a new `Order` will be marked as `Added` after the `Product`s have been attached to the context in their appropriate states.

Side note: `AddOrUpdate` is intended for use in Seed scripts during migrations. For regular creating/updating there may be more economical methods using *stub entities*.

Comment: Oooh... That's why... Awesome explanation: +1. As for the choice of *AddOrUpdate*, I've heard before it's not meant to be used this way but it's really convenient not to be forced to think if the object is being updated or if it's new. I kind of prefer using a single storage method and let the EF decide what to do. Would you say it's unwise in the long run? I'm open to adapting another way if recommended by an experienced person.

Comment: It's convenient and if it doesn't cause any performance problems I'd go for it. With *larger* volumes of data it's really not recommended though. But if you search Google for "Entity Framework stub entities" you'll get examples of how to do inserts/updates with the least possible database roundtrips.

Answer (score 1):

Entity framework does not have a cascade update feature please see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23084986/cascade-update-in-entity-framework%22post%22). The way you are handling it is probably the best way if it's simple. For complex object graph I have used [graphdiff](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RefactorThis.GraphDiff/)

Comment: Darn... I was sure that I was supposed to get the small thingies automagically created for me. In fact, in one project we had the problem that we did **not** want them to be implicitly created so we needed to clear up the stuff **prior** to *SaveChanges* But to be frank, it might have to do with some other stuff - said project was big and had some technical debt. In the post you linked to, they talk about *cascade **update*** not *cascade **add***. Does it matter?

Comment: I would think both would be important. Unless you only create. But I believe if you could cascade insert you would be able cascade update. I have found this extension helpful [graphdiff](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RefactorThis.GraphDiff/) this should do what you want.